# Read line by line java

Tags: java, file, set

I have a textfile which looks like this:

```
1 
2 3
4 5
6 7
```

I want to have 2 strings that are the values of same line. Example:

String s1 will be 2, String s2 will be 3

I tried like this:

```
    File file = new File("e:\\read.txt");
    if (file.exists()){
     FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
     LineNumberReader ln = new LineNumberReader(fr);
        while (ln.getLineNumber() == 0){

            s=Integer.parseInt(ln.readLine());
         System.out.println(s);
        }
        DisjointSetLinkedList dsj=new DisjointSetLinkedList();
        while(ln.getLineNumber()>0)
        {

           String [] tokens = ln.readLine().split(" ");
           s1=tokens[0];
           System.out.println( s1);
        }
```

I have to make union between 2 strings, that are on the same line:

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the union of 2 Strings? Can you post a sample input/output to make it more clearer?

Comment: You mean *concatenate*?

Comment: no, I have a method called Union , that takes as arguments 2 strings. All that I want is to take those strings from a file. If I have on a line : 3 4 , I will take string1=3 and string2=4  .

Comment: But... you already have it, taking your example file you could do string1=tokens[0] and string2=tokens[1]... what is your problem then?

Comment: my problem is that tokens[0] is the entire first row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sth like that is easier:

```
    try {
        File file = new File("numbers.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your second loop to :

```
    String line = null;
    while ((line = ln.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
        String s1 = tokens[0];
        String s2 = tokens[1];
        System.out.println("s1 = " + s1 + " s2 = " + s2);
    }
```

Otherwise you'll have `NullPointerException` when trying to access last line read with `ln.readLine()`.

You also don't need `while loop` to read first line, just read it once.

Answer (score 1):

if you have token[0] as the entire first row you can union like this

```
for(int i=2; i<token.length;i+2)
   System.out.println("UNION: "+Union(token[i-2], token[i]));
```